# CSS Table Columns not lining up

Tags: css, css-tables

I have the following Table example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu9y3/

Which is based on the Telerik example here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/Grid/Paging?theme=vista which is a UI component I am using in an app I am building.

As you can see they use two separate tables to achieve the fixed header and scrollable content. BUT the headers and columns in both tables still line up correctly.

Even if I **REMOVE** the style from the `<col>` in the Telerik examples using Web Inspector the columns will still line up... And they are **NOT** using jQuery to adjust the width. So how come they have their columns lining up and mine do not?

How are they doing this?

Comment: what is there not to understand? Set the property table-layout: fixed for the tables and set the a fixed width on the col. Simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `table-layout: fixed;` makes the table line up ;)

Comment: Yeah but you never posted it as an answer so therefore I had to answer it myself! (note it only fixes the issue some of the time though)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are having issues is because you are using two separate tables. Tables adjust column width to the longest unbroken content. The way Telerik does it, they have four columns and have set the widths explicitly in all but the third column. This allows the third column to expand and fill the remaining space.

Using `table-layout:fixed` will help but it will make all your columns evenly spaced regardless of content. I recommend setting the `width` of each column, or better yet make a `class` for each width and reuse that on the appropriate columns.

[Lined up sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LxLcu/2/)

I don't use classes in my example but I think you get the idea. I used `overflow:hidden` on `th` and `td` to make sure that longer content doesn't display over the other cells of the table. I also think the visual effect of the table works better with fewer columns seven or eight columns might be a bit overkill, but that's my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Google Chrome, and when I open up the editor (`F12`) to Telerik's site and change the settings, they start not lining up. I've done some research, and according to [W3.org on `<col>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#adef-scope), it looks like there is no way to globally name a `<col>` that you can use in multiple talbes (sadly).

Also, in Telerik's example, it appears that the `<col>` definitions specify a width in the tag itself (likely manually placed via some JS). I think this is the only way to do it other than setting specific CSS rules, but that may not work as well as a more dynamic solution.

Best of luck!

Comment: Yeah but I've used the Telerik stuff and the widths are set in the CSharp behind the scenes but if you take them off then they still line up unless you set the cols at diff widths in the header to the body table.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are wanting now. I think the answer to your question is that there are some default settings in the internal classes, or that if the widths are negative or 0, then automatic values are used. Unfortunately I do not have this code, and it is not an open source project. As I said, when I examined the raw rendered html code, the cols contain specified widths. This means that when you are using it, it will likely always specify a width value. I hope this helps, and I would recommend you at least retag this question to include .NET and/or ASP.

Comment: Hi think you've misunderstood. The inline styling is created by the .NET code BUT can be removed and it STILL lines the columns up so that's how I know the inline widths arn't the reason the columns line up on that demo as I can recreate it without the widths in my app. So I'm trying to figure out how why mine don't and theirs do? This isn't a .NET question as no .NET is used in the table in the rendered HTML and any javascript would be seen front-end.